# Normalization in Tensorflow, text classification

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, normalization

Few days ago i read about text classification with tensorflow, i found this rep on github, and build my own model based on example: https://github.com/dmesquita/understanding_tensorflow_nn

It works well, but i don't understand:

```
for text in texts:
    layer = np.zeros(total_words,dtype=float)
    for word in text.split(' '):
        layer[word2index[word.lower()]] += 1
```

When the same word comes second time, it increases value in layer (+=1), but where is normalization? I read that neuralnetworks works with values between 0 and 1 for input. I scanned all code, but can't find normalization. Can any body explain, why? Is it mistake in example?

And second question, when we build vocab in this example, we use Counter():

```
    for text in newsgroups_train.data:
         for word in text.split(' '):
             vocab[word.lower()]+=1
```

We increase vocab element every time we caught a word, for what? We not use this later.

Comment: It looks like it's counting the frequency of words.

Comment: Yes, it's word counting. Is it a good idea pass word count to neural network without normalization?